# How do I fix "Commands out of sync" error when running multiple queries?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting this error:

> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Here is my code:

```
$sql_moneyboxs = "SELECT SUM(Amount) AS inflow
        FROM payment_details WHERE DATE(created)='$todayDate' and paymentMode='cash' GROUP BY DATE(created)";   

$sql_moneyboxs .= "SELECT SUM(Amount) AS inflow
        FROM payment_details WHERE DATE(created)='$todayDate' and paymentMode='card' GROUP BY DATE(created)";

if(mysqli_multi_query($link,$sql_moneyboxs)){
    do{
        if($result=mysqli_store_result($link)){ // ignore if no record set
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                    echo $row['inflow'];
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
    } while(mysqli_more_results($link) && mysqli_next_result($link));
}
if($error_mess=mysqli_error($link)){
    echo $error_mess; // here is the problem
}
```

Comment: What error message did you get?

Comment: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: how to take row value from these two select queries?

Comment: You probably need to add a semi-colon at the end of the first query, inside of the quotes.

Comment: `Getting "Error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" after running a multi-query? Make sure you've cleared out the queue of results.` : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php#110155

Comment: like this GROUP BY DATE(created);"

Comment: Yup, that is exactly where you would need the semi-colon

Comment: i put semicolon after that also am getting same error sir.I dont know how to solve this issue..I tried a lot.

Comment: @aynber any other solution u have?

Comment: Nope. All I have is the link I provided. Two other people commenting on the documentation talk about the Out of Sync error.

Comment: @aynber i tried that code that u shared to me.inside while loop selected row is not printing at all.

Answer (score 0):

First, there needs to be a semi-colon `;` between SQL statements when running via phpMyAdmin or mysql-workbench, etc.  That will probably fix your error message.

But ....

Since the only difference between your two queries is the value of the `paymentMode` column, why not either use a `UNION` or handle it via the SQL in some other way?  This way you'll have one SQL command, you'll have one set of results to loop through, etc.

Comment: two queryies will call on specific condition otherwise will call individually(when doing individually its working fine.When the situation of calling two queries that time am getting error message like commands out of sync)